# C# WebApi DbContext uses same context for multiple request

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

Im building a `C# Web Api` with `Entity Framework 7`. (Setup with template `ASP.NET Core Web Api`)
In it I have some middleware that access the database. Now, this works fine untill multiple requests are fired at the api at the same time. I then get a `System.InvalidOperationException:` that states:

```
A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. 
This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. 
For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
```

While I understand the issue (`DbContext` is not thread safe) I cannot get the Api to generate a new `DbContext` for every requests.

So if I start my project it opens up a documentation page. And that page requests a couple of js and css files. The browser requestst that parallel. But as these are all different requests, I expect a new DbContext for every one of these request but that is obviously not the case.

I use `DI (Dependancy Injection)` to get the `DbContext` in all the functions and in `Services` I use `AddDbContext`:

```
webAppBuilder.Services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, MyDbContext>(
      options => options.UseSqlServer(
            webAppBuilder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"),
            x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()
       )
);
```

I've tried changing the  `Lifespan` (which has `Scoped` as default) to `Transient` and to `Singleton` but none of it works.

The middleware that uses the `DbContext` is setup like

```
public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IWebHostEnvironment env, IDbContext dbContext, Configuration configuration)
{
   Env = env;
   Next = next;
   RecyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
   DbContext = dbContext;
   Configuration = configuration;
}

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{

   ... //Get api key from context

   var apiKeyInformation = DbContext.ApiKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApiKey == apiKey);

   ... //Do something with the api key
}
```

The middleware is registered like this:

```
webApplication.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the "Do something with DbContext" part

Comment: The middleware has a singleton lifetime, there's additional work to change the lifetime of the DbContext it uses to make that per request: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2#per-request-middleware-dependencies

Comment: @qujck Thanks, That is going to help me big time. I didn't know that the middleware had a different lifetime then the controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the dbContext in through the constructor, which is only called once during application lifetime: [Middleware Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0#:%7E:text=Middleware%20should%20follow%20the%20Explicit%20Dependencies%20Principle%20by%20exposing%20its%20dependencies%20in%20its%20constructor.%20Middleware%20is%20constructed%20once%20per%20application%20lifetime.)

You should resolve the DBContext during `InvokeAsync`:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetService<IDbContext>();

   ... //Get api key from context

   var apiKeyInformation = dbContext.ApiKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApiKey == apiKey);

   ... //Do something with the api key
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! Really aprieciate it. Was breaking my head over it. But learning that middleware has a different lifetime is something I will never forget now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create new instances of `DbContext` using [`IDbContextFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbcontextfactory-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)
inside your middleware